# Async download of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, asynchronous

The following code is an async beginner exploration into asynchronous file downloads, to try and improve the download time of files from a specific website.

---

**Tasks:**

The tasks are as follows:

1. Visit https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/mental-health-services-monthly-statistics
2. Extract the latest publication link. It is the top link under *Latest Statistics* and is the first match returned by css selector `.cta__button`.

   [image]

N.B. Each month this link updates so the next monthly publication e.g. 8 Apr 2021 the link will update to that associated with *Mental Health Services Monthly Statistics Performance January, Provisional February 2021*.

3. Visit the extracted link: https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/mental-health-services-monthly-statistics/performance-december-2020-provisional-january-2021 and, from there, extract the download links for all the files listed under *Resources*; currently 17 files.

   [image]
4. Finally, download all those files, using the retrieved urls, and save them to the location specified by `folder` variable.

---

**Set-up:**

Python 3.9.0 64-bit Windows 10

---

**Request:**

I would appreciate any suggested improvements to this code e.g. should I have re-factored the co-routine `fetch_download_links` into two co-routines, each with a `ClientSession`, where one co-routine gets the initial link to where to get the resources, and the second co-routine to retrieve the actual resource links?

---

**mhsmsAsynDownloads.py**

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import urllib

async def fetch_download_links(url:str) -> list:   
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        r = await session.get(url, ssl = False)
        html = await r.text()
        soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
        link = 'https://digital.nhs.uk' + soup.select_one('.cta__button')['href']
        r = await session.get(link, ssl = False)
        html = await r.text()
        soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
        files = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.attachment a')]

        return files


async def place_file(source: str) -> None:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        file_name = source.split('/')[-1]
        file_name = urllib.parse.unquote(file_name)
        r = await session.get(source, ssl = False)
        content = await r.read()
    
    async with aiofiles.open(folder + file_name, 'wb') as f:
        await f.write(content)

    
async def main():
    tasks = []
    urls = await fetch_download_links('https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/mental-health-services-monthly-statistics')
    
    for url in urls:

        tasks.append(place_file(url))   
    
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        
folder = 'C:/Users/<User>/OneDrive/Desktop/testing/'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    t1 = time.perf_counter()   
    print("process started...")   
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    os.startfile(folder[:-1])
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Completed in {t2-t1} seconds.')
```

---

**References/Notes:**

1. I wrote this after watching an [async tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/-hZPoYEajWk) by Andrei Dumitrescu.
   The example above is my own
2. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v0.20.0/client.html
3. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html
4. Data is publicly available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me, you could potentially shave off some repetition, but it's not like it matters that much for a small script.

That said, I'd reuse the session, inline a few variables, fix the naming (constants should be uppercase) and use some standard library tools like `os.path` to make the script more error-proof.  The `list` return type could also be more concrete and mention that it's a list of strings for example.

Also, and that's a bit more important, I'd rather not have a script slurp in the whole HTTP response like that!  Who knows how big the files are, plus it's wasteful ... better to stream the response directly to disk!  [Thankfully the APIs do exist](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html), using `.content.iter_any` (or `_chunked` if you prefer to have a fixed chunk size) you can just iterate over each read data block and write them to the file like so:

```
import time
import os
import os.path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import urllib
import typing


STATISTICS_URL = 'https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/mental-health-services-monthly-statistics'
OUTPUT_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/<User>/OneDrive/Desktop/testing/'


async def fetch_download_links(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str) -> typing.List[str]:
    r = await session.get(url, ssl=False)
    soup = bs(await r.text(), 'lxml')
    link = 'https://digital.nhs.uk' + soup.select_one('.cta__button')['href']

    r = await session.get(link, ssl=False)
    soup = bs(await r.text(), 'lxml')
    return [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.attachment a')]


async def place_file(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, source: str) -> None:
    r = await session.get(source, ssl=False)

    file_name = urllib.parse.unquote(source.split('/')[-1])
    async with aiofiles.open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, file_name), 'wb') as f:
        async for data in r.content.iter_any():
            await f.write(data)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        urls = await fetch_download_links(session, STATISTICS_URL)
        await asyncio.gather(*[place_file(session, url) for url in urls])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    print('process started...')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    os.startfile(OUTPUT_FOLDER[:-1])
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Completed in {t2-t1} seconds.')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will need a little time to digest but very much appreciate what I have seen so far +